# Appending environment variable with jade variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I want to append an environment variable with jade local variable. May I know how can I do it? The below code is giving me an error.

```
each m in menu
  li
    a(href=#{env.URL}+m.slug)= m.name
```

`#{env.URL}` is the environment variable and m.slug is the local jade variable.

Answer (score 1):

As within `a(...)`, you are in the jade scope, you can simply access the env variable like any local jade variable
`a(href="'" + env.URL + m.slug + "'")= m.name`